# "Object is currently in use elsewhere", but where is it in use, and who is using it?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

There are lots of answers describing WHY this error is occurring, but I can't find any that explain how to determine (a) which routine is failing, (b) which object are we talking about, and (c) which other bit of code is using the object at the moment that it is wanted. Normally we get a line-number at least, but for some reason this error wants to keep me guessing. Any ideas? (This is a large program with a number of threads running.)

```
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>MyLargeProgram.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Object is currently in use elsewhere.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
       at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
       at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
       at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

The application creates a large image that is eventually show on a PictureBox. The final image is created in 4 stages from 4 other images by Threads that copy one of the existing images, make changes to it, then save it again to that image. There are flags to stop an image being accessed if it is in use elsewhere. The final Thread takes the 4th image, makes changes to it, then sets a Clone of the modified image as the PictureBox image.

```
    SyncLock bm
        PbWM.Image?.Dispose()
        PbWM.Image = CType(bm.Clone, Bitmap)
    End SyncLock
```

I thought that I had used sufficent SyncLocks and flags, but perhaps not. I do not know why System.Transactions appear there. I am not importing that.

---

On the other matter of locking: this is the method I was using for replacing image content. Is there a better way to do it?

```
    ' The Thread enters with Bitmap bm1..

    ' I make a working copy of bm1
    Using bm0 As Bitmap = CType(bm1.Clone, Bitmap)
        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            ' Some image drawing is done here
        End Using

        SyncLock bm
            ' Replace bm1 with the altered image
            bm1 = CType(bm0.Clone, Bitmap)
        End SyncLock
    End Using
```

Perhaps this is the best way?

```
    ' The Thread enters with Bitmap bm1..

    ' I make a working copy of bm1
    Using bm0 As Bitmap = CType(bm1.Clone, Bitmap)
        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            ' Some image drawing is done here
        End Using

        Dim thisLock As New Object
        SyncLock thisLock
            ' Replace bm1 with the altered image
            bm1 = CType(bm0.Clone, Bitmap)
        End SyncLock
    End Using
```

or this?

```
    ' The Thread enters with Bitmap bm1..

    ' I make a working copy of bm1
    Using bm0 As Bitmap = CType(bm1.Clone, Bitmap)
        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            ' Some image drawing is done here
        End Using

        Dim thisLock As New Object
        SyncLock thisLock
            ' Replace bm1 with the altered image
            bm1 = New Bitmap(bm0)
        End SyncLock
    End Using
```

Comment: What does the application code do and why does `System.Transactions` appear here? Is the application trying to create images by rendering on PictureBox objects? These aren't thread safe and *only* meant for displaying data on a screen, not generating image files. They use limited GDI resources meant for screen rendering. It's a lot cheaper and faster to use an image processing library like eg ImageSharp instead

Comment: We need to see the code producing this error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for answering. I have modified my question with more info. I was not aware of ImageSharp.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - The problem is that I do not know which bit of code is producing the error, so I cannot show it to you ! That is why I am posting the question: I would love to know which bit of code is producing the error: normally an error tells you the line number, or stops and points to the section, but in this case it does not.

Comment: Why would you need code that affects the Image property of a PictureBox inside a SyncLock? That should only be executed on the UI thread to begin with so there should never be a possibility of it being executed on multiple threads in the first place. That would appear to be the source of the issue so stop doing that and the problem will go away.

Comment: Read the Remarks section of [DependentTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.dependenttransaction) and [Managing Concurrency with DependentTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/managing-concurrency-with-dependenttransaction) -- If you need a lock, create an `Object` and lock on that instead of, e.g., `Me` or an object you're working on

Comment: The stack trace tells you where "elsewhere" happened.  It is the PictureBox control that needs to repaint its Image property, with high likelihood that it is PbWM.  SyncLock can only work when it is used to protect *all* code that accesses a shared object.  And of course PictureBox doesn't know anything about the object that stores the lock state (PbWM again in this case).  There isn't enough code to propose a better solution, get ahead by *not* using Bitmap.Clone(), it can't solve this problem.  Make a deep copy of the image with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - yes, good point about updating the PictureBox.Image within another Thread - I will fix that. Also about the lock. However, the source of the issue, as I think the error code mentions, is when I try to get the Width of an image, or the Width of a PictureBox. I'd like to find the instance of that that cause the error. Surely there is some way to find that out.

Comment: @HansPassant - I have edited my question to show what I think you mean, assuming I was changing the content of a Bitmap. As jmcilhinney said, I should not alter the Picturebox from within a Thread.

Comment: No, that's not the cause.  The exception is raised by the Image class, not the PictureBox class.

Comment: As Hans says, it's getting the `Size` of the `Image` that is the problem, not that of the `PictureBox`. It would appear that the `PictureBox` is trying to paint and it can't do so because the `Image` is in use elsewhere. Notice that `OnPaint` method of the `PictureBox` is trying to get the `Size` of the `Image` in order to draw it and that's what's failing. I'd probably suggest that you only work with the `Image` object on the UI thread as well, if possible.